# CSS float:right doesn't work on JQuery UI selectmenu

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm working with jQuery UI to make a search form.
I was able to get the results that I wanted, until I tried to align a `select` menu on the right side of my form with `CSS`.

Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to do : https://jsfiddle.net/z829pay7/15/.

And the corresponding code below :

**HTML code**

```
 <form action="/" method="get" >

        <input type="button" id ="button3" value="Button3" class="button left"/>

        <input type="button" id ="button2" value="Button2" class="button right"/>

        <input type="button" id ="button1" value="Button1" class="button right"/>

        <select name="select" id="select" class="select">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

**JavaScript code**

```
      $(".select").selectmenu({
          width:200
      });
      $(".button").button();
```

**CSS code**

```css
.right {
    float:right;
    clear:left;
}

.button {
    vertical-align : middle;
}

.select {
    float: right;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

I'm using `float:right` on jQuery UI buttons and it is working as expected.
On `select` menus the CSS seems to be ignored.

I also can't find a way to align the `buttons` and the `select` menu vertically.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong !

Edit (2015/08/31 13:17): I've updated the fiddle link.

Comment: select menu doesn't take css because it is hidden with display:none

Comment: @philippe is this what you are expecting [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/fw40o1r8/2/)

Comment: Im' sorry, it looks like I forgot to save my JSfiddle ! I juste edited it : https://jsfiddle.net/z829pay7/15/.  
@Webruster, what I am expecting is to have my menu aligned on the right of the screen, but on the left of Button1. Ideally, it should be of the same size, and vertically aligned with the buttons.

Comment: @Philippe you want your dropdown between `button3` and `button 1` .from the fiddle which you provided

Comment: @Webruster Yes ! As it is right now, but instead of beeing next to button3, i want it next to button1.

Comment: @Philippe Here is ur requirement as you asked [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/z829pay7/16/)

Comment: @Webruster Thanks for this update, after a bit of testing and reading the answers, I was able to get to the result I wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/bilgamesh/pLbja708/1/  
  All the answers were right, but Radu was the first to post :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88401/discussion-between-webruster-and-philippe).

Comment: @Philippe no problem , you satisfied with answers right ? you got your answer right  .. if so then i am glad that i am able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've wrapped the select in a div so it looks like this:

```
<div class="right">
<select name="select" id="select" class="select">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

[fiddler link](https://jsfiddle.net/fw40o1r8/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! It works by adding a div. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bilgamesh/pLbja708/1/. However, the height is still ignored by the select menu.   So I just tweaked the height of the button to match the height of the select menu.

Answer (score 1):

I have added a `div` and to this i have added a class by name `test` . with this class i can able to assign the css for `select`

here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kri4shna/z829pay7/16/)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because Bootstrap hides the *select* and put another element on the position of the *select* to achieve that visual, so any CSS rule applied to the select will not affect the visual. I recommend you to use the browser developer tools to check the code when this kind of thing happens.

To achieve what you want, I think the best way is to wrap the select with a *div* containing the "right" class, this way, when Bootstrap switch the *select* with a *div*, the wrapper *div* will make sure the content inside receives the CSS rule you want. It will look like this:

```
<div class="right"> 
    <select name="select" id="select" class="select">
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this style:

```
  <style>
      #sex-button {
        float: right;
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
  </style>

<select name="sex" id="sex">
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```